# Java Object[] looping error

Tags: java

Trying to loop thru a list Object[] using for loop:

```
String query = "Employee.findEmployeeIdByEmployeeType";
List<Object[]> empIdDtoLst = (List<Object[]>)em.createNamedQuery(query).setParameter("employeeType", empType).getResultList();

for (Object[] result : empIdDtoLst) {  <-- ERROR
    logger.info("Number " + result);

    Object[] empDetailIdDtoLst = (Object[])em.createNamedQuery(query).setParameter("empDetailsId", result).getSingleResult();  <-- USE HERE
}
```

I'm getting an error in the for loop line:

```
2015-09-25T14:50:09.115+0800|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[DispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet DispatcherServlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
at com.syntronic.dao.impl.JobDaoImpl.getListOfEmployees(JobDaoImpl.java:352)
at com.syntronic.service.impl.JobServiceImpl.getListOfEmployees(JobServiceImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Basically, I need the values (integers) to be used as stated above to find records (id in long format) based on the looping.  Any idea why its throwing the error?

I did try changing the Object[] to long[] but same error occurs.

EDIT: query

```
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findEmployeeIdByEmployeeType", query="SELECT e.empId FROM Employee e where e.employeeType=:employeeType")
```

Comment: The problem lies in `setParameter("empDetailsId", result)` seems like given method is expecting Long and you are passing Object[]

Comment: Have you tried casting to `Long` instead?  No arrays, but a straight-up single entity?  Since that's what you're expecting from your query, that is.

Comment: can you post the `query` you're using? I'm guessing that your query only select one field instead of multiple fields.

Comment: Was able to fix it by adding an extra field in select. Assuming its not the proper way to fix it as I only need the id.

Comment: You can try with `em.createNamedQuery(query,Long.class)` and fetch result in `List<Long>`. This should work in your case if you are getting only ids.

Comment: @ArnoldCristobal If only you can post more codes, it will be easier to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from  the fact that you are selecting one field so you'll have a List of Object not a List of Object[]. As the selected field is your id, just set the type to Long.

```
 List<Long> empIdDtoLst = (List<Long>)em.createNamedQuery(query).setParameter("employeeType", empType).getResultList();
 for (Long result : empIdDtoLst) {  
     logger.info("Number " + result);
 }
```

This way you select only one field so return only a list of this particular type of object.